# Woocommerce, get order status from order note

Tags: woocommerce

```
function get_last_but_one_order_status($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $status_history = array();

    // Get all order notes
    $order_notes = wc_get_order_notes(array(
        'order_id' => $order_id,
        'type' => 'system_status_change',
        'orderby' => 'date_created',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ));

    // Extract status history from notes
    foreach ($order_notes as $note) {
        $status_history[] = $note->content;
    }

    $status_count = count($status_history);

    if ($status_count < 2) {
        return ''; // No previous status available
    }

    // Get the last but one status
    $last_but_one_status = $status_history[$status_count - 2];

    return $last_but_one_status;
}
```

In this code I am returning the last but one note in order notes history. I need to extract the meta key of this order status, the function returns only the text of the note

Comment: Please, what does mean *"the last but one note"*P

Answer (score 1):

In the comment, you mentioned you need the second one from the top of order statuses. So, I modified your code, try it and modify it as u see fit:

```php
function get_last_but_one_order_status($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $status_history = array();

    // Get all order notes of type 'system_status_change'
    $order_notes = wc_get_order_notes(array(
        'order_id' => $order_id,
        'type' => 'system_status_change',
        'orderby' => 'date_created',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ));

    // Extract status history from notes
    foreach ($order_notes as $note) {
        $status_change_notes[] = $note->content;
    }

    $status_change_notes_count = count($status_change_notes);

    if ($status_change_notes_count < 2) {
        return ''; // No previous status change available
    }

    // Get the last but one status-change note
    $last_but_one = $status_change_notes[$status_change_notes_count - 2];

    // Use regular expressions to extract the final status from the note
    if (preg_match('/to ([a-z\-]+)/i', $last_but_one, $matches)) {
        $last_but_one_status = $matches[1];
        return $last_but_one_status;
    }

    return '';
}
```

Usage example:

```
$order_id = 13;
$new_order_status = get_last_but_one_order_status($order_id);
if (!empty($new_order_status)) {
    $order->update_status($new_order_status, 'Order status changed programmatically.');
}
```

If your order statuses have keys (slugs) which are different from their corresponding names, then you would have to get the slug in a separate function, like so:

```php
function get_order_status_slug_from_name($status_name) {
    $statuses = get_terms('shop_order_status', array('hide_empty' => 0));
    foreach ($statuses as $status) {
        if ($status->name == $status_name) {
            return $status->slug;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function get_last_but_one_order_status($order_id) {
    // ...
    // ...

    // Use regular expressions to extract the status name from the note
    if (preg_match('/to ([a-z\-]+)/i', $last_but_one, $matches)) {
        $status_name = $matches[1];
        $status_slug = get_order_status_slug_from_name($status_name);
        if ($status_slug) {
            return $status_slug;
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, actually I need the status for the last but one, so the second from the top of order statuses. What I need is the meta key or the slug of the order status, for example On Hold status has url on-hold, Processing has url processing, and so on, because I need after that to update order status with this status. For example $order->update_status('on-hold') or $order->update_status($last_but_one_order_status);

In your ex I think I get the text not the url, and also the url of the status can be different than the name/ label of the status, so will not work with preg_match

Comment: thanks again, but like I said before, your code extracts the first word after "to" in the order status note, so this is not what I need it because you can't update order status with this word, you need the order status url. So your code will run like this
$order->update_status('FirstWordOfStatus') but I need this:
$order->update_status($order-status-url)

Comment: @art what you want doesn't make much sense - according to the official documentation https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_orderupdate_status/ - the parameter `$order_status` in `$order->update_status($order_status)` accepts order status slugs for example `$order->update_status('completed')`, not an URL

Comment: If you have other order statuses then these 7: `pending`, `failed`, `on-hold`, `processing`, `completed`, `refunded`, `cancelled`, you will have to modify the REGEX pattern in the `preg_match()` function to capture your custom order statuses.

Comment: Yes, the slug I meant, but the slug can be different than the status name which you are extracting from the note with preg_match(). For example order status name can be Custom status(displayed in note) and his slug to be my-custom-order-status which is not in the note, so I need to find a away to get the slug so I can use it in the $order->update_status() method

Comment: @art If your order statuses have keys (slugs) which are different from their corresponding names, then you would have to get the slug in a separate function - I have updated the answer.

Comment: the $new_order_status is empty

Comment: I cannot help u with that, I think you have to debug the code by yourself for example by using `var_dump()` to see what data you are getting and go on from there. People use different version of WP/woocommerce, some functions might not work as they used to.